# Render multiple models with pk in a single view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to pass lesson.price, and lesson.invoice_id from Lesson model and student.student_id from Student Model into the single view so that I can display them in a template.
However, Lesson model has a field "student" which has a foreign key to User, not to Student model. You will see my code for view class is wrong since I have no clue how to get a proper student object with a primary which is used for lesson object.
How could I get a proper student object with lesson_id primary key in view class?

```
class User(AbstractUser):
'''User model for authentication and lessons authoring.'''

class Role(models.TextChoices):
    ADMIN="ADMIN",'Admin'
    STUDENT="STUDENT",'Student'
    TEACHER="TEACHER",'Teacher'
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
username   = models.CharField(
    max_length=30,
    unique=True,
    validators=[RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^@\w{3,}$',
        message='Username must consist of @ followed by at least three alphanumericals.'
    )]
)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
email      = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False)
gender     = models.CharField(max_length=255)
address    = models.TextField(default='')
baseRole   = Role.ADMIN
role       = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Role.choices)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.role = self.baseRole
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return  self.first_name+" "+self.last_name

class Student(User):
student_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=uuid.uuid4)
baseRole = User.Role.STUDENT
student = StudentManager()


class Lesson(models.Model):
lesson_id   = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
lesson_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
student     = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='studying', unique=True)
teacher     = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='teaching')
start_time  = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
interval    = models.IntegerField()
duration    = models.IntegerField()
created_at  = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
is_request  = models.BooleanField()
number      = models.IntegerField(default=0)
invoice_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=uuid.uuid4)

@property
def price(self):
    return self.duration/5 * self.number



@staticmethod
def durations():
    return [20, 30, 40, 45, 60]

@staticmethod
def subjects():
    return ['Guitar','Violin','Piano', 'Voice', 'Cello','Ukulele','Recorder', 'Drums']

@staticmethod
def intervals():
    return [2, 5, 7, 10, 14]

def __str__(self):
    return "Lesson id: "+str(self.lesson_id)+", Student id: "+str(self.student.id)+", Student: "+str(self.student)
```

views.py

```
def invoice(request, lesson_id):
lesson = Lesson.objects.get(lesson_id=lesson_id)
student = Lesson.student.get(student_id=lesson.student.student_id)
return render(request, 'invoice.html', {'lesson':lesson, "student":student})
```

invoice.html

```
{% extends 'student/student_home_base.html' %}
{% block student_content %}

<head>Your Invoice</head>
<p>Your invoice reference number is{{lesson.student_id}}-{{lesson.invoice_id}}</p>

<p>Your Total Payable is {{lesson.price}}</p>

<p>Once you're done paying, please click this button below.</p>
<input type="submit" value="submit">


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lesson = Lesson.objects.get(lesson_id=lesson_id) # you get the Lesson object
student = lesson.student # call the student attribute on the variable "lesson" not the Class Lesson
```

Note that the variable `lesson` contains an instance of the `Lesson` class.
Note that the variable `student` will actually contain an instance of the `User` class.
If you want the `Student` instance you should do:

```
student = lesson.student.student
```

where `lesson` in the Lesson object, the first `.student` calls the foreignkey relationship with `User` and the second `.student` is the relative Student object related by an OneToOne implicit relationship (with User) thanks to the multi-table inheritance.
all details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).